# on Change event in select with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, magento2, onselect

I have a problem how to call onchanges knock js to my select option, i already have a function and html, but when i choose the select option, nothing changes

```
<select data-bind="event:{change:setSelectedStation() },
                   options: seedData,
                   optionsText: 'text',
                   optionsValue: 'value'">
</select>
```

here is my function

```
setSelectedStation: function(element, KioskId){
     this.getPopUp().closeModal();
     $('.selected-station').html(element);
     $('[name="popstation_detail"]').val(element);
     $('[name="popstation_address"]').val(KioskId);

     $('[name="popstation_text"]').val(element);
     // console.log($('[name="popstation_text"]').val());
     this.isSelectedStationVisible(true);
},
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use knockout's two-way data-binds instead of manually subscribing to UI events.

Knockout's `value` data-bind listens to UI changes and automatically keeps track of the latest value for you.

Instead of replacing HTML via jQuery methods, you use `text`, `attr` and other `value` bindings to update the UI whenever your selection changes.

If you want to perform additional work when a selection changes (e.g. closing a pop up), you `subscribe` to the selected value.

```js
var VM = function() {
  this.seedData = [
    { 
      text: "Item 1",
      data: "Some other stuff"
    },
    { 
      text: "Item 2",
      data: "Something else"
    },
    { 
      text: "Item 3",
      data: "Another thing"
    }
  ];
  
  this.selectedItem = ko.observable();
  
  this.selectedItem.subscribe(function(latest) {
    console.log("Input changed");
  }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="
        value: selectedItem,
        options: seedData,
        optionsText: 'text'">
</select>

<!-- ko with: selectedItem -->
<p>
  Your selection: <span data-bind="text: data"></span>
</p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: we cannot call by one function only?

Comment: You *can*, bit you shouldn't... if you chose to use knockout as your framework, it's best to stuff "the knockout way". If you want to manage your own event handling and update UI elements one by one, it's better to just use jQuery and skip knockout altogether.

Comment: but if i want enter the value of parameter in selectedItem, what should i put into it?

Comment: @user3297291 Tried the same but getting error as: Unable to process binding "options: function (){return seedData }"
Message: seedData is not defined

Comment: what about ajax when select changed? How do I put it in knockoutjs way.

Comment: @DoniWibowo If you update your selection in code, knockout will update the UI for you. E.g.: `this.selectedItem(this.seedData[0])` will reset the select box to the first item in the list.

Comment: I don't understand how <span data-bind="text: data"></span> refers to seedData.data property.or the selectedItem variable

Comment: @jimscafe There's a `with` binding on `selectedItem` around it. The *binding context* of the `<span>` is therefore an element of `seedData`. Each of those items contains a `data` property, allowing us to bind to it.

Comment: @user3297291 - Wow, I hadn't got that far with the documentation. Now I see it - thank you