# Set on change event with Knockout into select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, dom-events

I have a dropdown working nice:

```
<select class="picker-select" data-bind="options: searchOptions, select:{}, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedSearchOption" ></select>
```

Now I want to execute a function when selection changes but it does not seem to work.

---

What I've tried:

[**`onchange` event**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp):

```
onchange="actionWhenChange()"   // also tried without parenthesys
```

**MODEL:**

```
function actionWhenChange(event) {
  console.log("doing stuff");
};
```

**ERROR:**

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: actionWhenChange is not defined

---

And with [knockout `event` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) (also tried without parenthesys)

```
data-bind="event: { onchange: actionWhenChange() }, ... more bindings
```

**MODEL:**

```
self.actionWhenChange = function (event) {
  console.log("doing stuff");
}
```

But I get no error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43158167/3297291). The question is formulated differently, but the answer is the same.

Comment: I.e.: in your model, you write: `self.selectedSearchOption.subscribe(self.actionWhenChange)`

Comment: @user3297291 I've fixed it using correct dom event... but I will try subscribe also just to see how it works, many thanks `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Well, finally found out what's going on :)

First solution wasn't working because the function could not be found as it was inside the model. That's why undefined error.

About second option, the [event binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html), knockout is handling DOM events, and `onchange` is not one of the DOM events as can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).

So solution was just remove the on from onchange and use the change event:

```
data-bind="event: { change: actionWhenChange }, ... more bindings
```

## BUT

The correct way to solve this is the stated by [`user3297291`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297291/user3297291): use subscribe to value observable inside the model in this way:

```
self.selectedSearchOption.subscribe(self.actionWhenChange) –
```

Hope this can help someone in the futue :)

Comment: While it's nice that you're sharing your solution, please have a look at the answer I linked in the comments. *Subscribing to the DOM's `change` event is an anti-pattern in knockout*. Subscribe to the observable instead. Also, you shouldn't call the method when passing it to the event binding: `event: { change: actionWhenChange }` is the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, I'm trying subscribe option, one question.... why use change event is an anti pattern??

Comment: When using knockout, you only care about your view model. Syncing the values in your viewmodel with the DOM is knockout's job and happens through data-binds. Event bindings are only used to react to *user input*. If you want to react to a change, you listen to changes in your view model without caring where they come from. That way, if the values changes by *any* means, you ensure your action is always called.

Comment: @user3297291 subscribe is not only working, but far more elegant and readable. I've edited my answer, but feel free to post a new answer if you want me to accept it. Many thanks again `:)`